# Error: nodejs nestjs 'npm run start' how do i solve this?

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs

I keep getting this error when i run npm run start at terminal. This is a nestJS default project.

```
Found 41 error(s).

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! backend@0.0.1 start: `nest start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the backend@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\eduar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-25T01_25_45_350Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\eduar\OneDrive\Escritorio\Fullstack\backend>
```

Also I get duplicate identifier errors, but I can post it because of character limits.

*This is the debug:*

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.14.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle backend@0.0.1~prestart: backend@0.0.1
6 info lifecycle backend@0.0.1~start: backend@0.0.1
7 verbose lifecycle backend@0.0.1~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle backend@0.0.1~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\eduar\OneDrive\Escritorio\Fullstack\backend\node_modules\.bin;D:\VMware\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;D:\Git\cmd;C:\Users\eduar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\eduar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Users\eduar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\eduar\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\eduar\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Users\eduar\OneDrive\Escritorio\flutter\bin;C:\Users\eduar\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\eduar\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
9 verbose lifecycle backend@0.0.1~start: CWD: C:\Users\eduar\OneDrive\Escritorio\Fullstack\backend
10 silly lifecycle backend@0.0.1~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'nest start' ]
11 silly lifecycle backend@0.0.1~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle backend@0.0.1~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: backend@0.0.1 start: `nest start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid backend@0.0.1
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\eduar\OneDrive\Escritorio\Fullstack\backend
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start"
18 verbose node v14.14.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error backend@0.0.1 start: `nest start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the backend@0.0.1 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I already try to reinstall npm packages and reinstall nestjs. As i said at the first, this is default project of nestjs and node

Answer (score -2):

It seems you have no @nestjs/cli installed globally.

```
npm i -g @nestjs/cli
```